# How can I right-click canvas to save as image instead of html?

Tags: kineticjs

The following code is working but how can I add a button to save the canvas as an image?

```
<input id="newtext" type="text" value="Hello!">
<button id="addbutton">Any this text</button>
<h2>The added text is draggable</h2>
<div id="container"></div>
```

A full code example can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pQYz9/)**.
Hi, I'm trying to use that example, but it doesn't explain how to save is as an image instead of a html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also working with older version of KJS, using the getCanvas method :

```
$("#save").click(function () {
         var dataUrl = layer.getCanvas().toDataURL();
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function () {
                $("body").append("<p>Right-click the image below & then 'save-as'</p>");
                document.body.appendChild(img);
            }
            img.src = dataUrl;
            //window.open(dataUrl);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SERH/

Answer (score 1):

**First**

Upgrade to the new version of KineticJS (the newer versions can export to images).

**Next**

Use `stage.toDataURL` to save the stage to an image and append that image to the page so the user can "right-click-save-as" on the image to save it to their local drive:

**Example code and a Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aFn57/

```
stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl) {
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            $("body").append("<p>Right-click the image below & then 'save-as'</p>");
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        img.src=dataUrl;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I was looking for.